# Invalid config field backend model: adminhtml/system_config_backend_customer_password_link_expirationperiod

Tags: php, magento-1.9

When I got to System>Configuration>Customers>Customer Configuration it errors. 
Report gives:

"Invalid config field backend model:adminhtml/system_config_backend_customer_password_link_expirationperiod".

I am using magento 1.9.2.4 and i have done followings

1. Disable all custom modules.
2. I have checked \app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Model\System\Config\Backend\Customer\Password\Link\Expirationperiod.ph file exist.

Now what is the reason for this error?

Please suggest

thanks